# Modern WinRT bitmap class suitable for efficient re-use

Tags: c++, image-processing, bitmap, real-time, c++-winrt

I need to do image processing work as fast as possible - milliseconds matter in my context. And I want to make use of modern image recognition techniques such as neural networks. Most of the examples I have looked at in Windows assume I am going to load one image once from one file and do one thing with it - not very useful :-( Either that or they are the [Yolo example](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML/tree/master/Samples/yolov4) which is a mixture of rocket science and techniques above my pay grade :-(

My simple problem is this: take a bitmap that is already in memory (e.g. `HBITMAP`, `ATL::CImage`, etc) and (ideally) have a [SoftwareBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.SoftwareBitmapSource?view=winrt-19041) point to that data, or at least copy that data into a `SoftwareBitmap`. After that, following [this Windows ML tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-started-desktop) I want to convert the image to a tensor, send it to my GPU, get results, and repeat millions of times over with as few overheads as possible.

So far I cannot find anything that allows me to point the bitmap buffer to a pre-existing in-memory bitmap.

If I'm forced to copy the entire bitmap each time, the obvious thing to try is to use `SoftwareBitmap.LockBuffer()` to obtain access to the pixel data, which I can then modify. But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap.lockbuffer?view=winrt-19041) tells me I'm not allowed to hold such a lock indefinitely, meaning I need to release it. The trouble is there is no way to unlock it without destroying the buffer, and no obvious way to use the buffer beyond the scope so long as the lock is held. That makes it impossible to get my data to the GPU :-(

[WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap?view=winrt-19041#methods) seems like it may be a useful class to consider, but the documentation and examples for it are sparse to say the least. So far it has not got me any closer to my goal, including by trying variations on [this theme](https://gist.github.com/saramgsilva/77d1b86b847393cd976e) :-(

It seems weird that there is not a direct and obvious way to set up a bitmap (or set of bitmaps in a circular buffer) and re-use them over and over for real-time image processing. What am I missing? Is it there, but just not documented, or in any obvious example?

Comment: You can't keep pointers to memory between two technologies bitmaps such as the (kinda legacy) HBITMAPs and WinRT bitmaps. You'll have to keep two copies if you want to keep two technologies. Or get rid of HBITMAPs (and I rewrite most of your existing code I guess).

Comment: That sounds... wrong. That would imply that there is no way (e.g. via shared memory) to pass legacy data to modern apps. Forcing the world to rewrite 30-50 years worth of code for the sake of one must-have modern widget is not a smart business model. My hope/belief is that the pixel data has the same format in many/most cases, while the wrapping structures may be different. I'm hoping only to avoid copying/reformatting the pixel data. Can you definitively say this is impossible?

Comment: You can "pass" legacy data to modern apps. The important word is "pointers". You can't share bitmap pointers between GDI and modern techs because modern techs are GPU-first. LockBuffer is the typical example of GPU->CPU mapping (and is very costly, relatively to what a GPU can do by itself).

Comment: Thanks - that is useful clarity lacking in all the reference material I've poured over in the past week...

Comment: Could you please tell me has your problem been resolved?

Comment: Yes and no - I am working on multiple things at once, and have not yet been able to find an article that describes how bitmaps have evolved from HBITMAP to WinRT in the "GPU-first" way that @SimonMourier mentions. I'd like to see something definitive as the basis for an answer.

Comment: We will consult other engineers for your problem. There may be some delays.

Comment: After consulting other engineers, it does not look like it would be possible to translate over the HBITMAP data in memory to SoftwareBitmap without needing to copy the bitmap bits.
Could you please tell me how you are getting HBITMAP data to begin with in your scenario, what you are reading the bitmap data from, and how you are getting the data and setting it in memory?

Comment: The data is coming from a live video camera. There are some pre-processing steps occurring in CPU memory prior to submitting it to the neural net via the GPU. It seems like we will have to re-architect the system to streamline the transfer from CPU memory to GPU memory. It would be helpful to have a demo project from Microsoft that shows how this might be done using modern classes & components.

Comment: Could you please provide us more information about the pre-processing steps you mentioned? You mentioned you are following the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-started-desktop#load-the-image), could you please tell me where you are having issues generating the SoftwareBitmaps of the captured video data? Lastly, from your last response, it seems like you have an idea of the changes to make to your project. Could you please tell me the update on your project, and how it has been going? I wonder if you are still requiring help with the issue.